# What kind of people can answer this riddle?

Tags: word, language

What kind of people can answer the following riddle?

> Call a=1, b=2, and so on. What is the longest common English word that can be made from only prime letters?

Comment: is 'a' a prime number?

Comment: No, 1 is not a prime 'round these parts.

Comment: Nobody, because it is not possible for one person to know the entirety of common English vernacular.  Or, alternatively, Queen Elizabeth II and nobody else.

Comment: I don't think this is a riddle - should the title be changed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Heh, yeah.. my next guess:

> SE Geeks

Comment: Could "S.E." be (tongue in cheek) added to the front of that to refer to the Stack Exchange version?

Comment: (To borrow from some other answers)
Beseems we seek SE web geek.

Comment: Changed per request

Comment: webgeeks seems like a good fit too.

Answer (score 9):

The question was "What kind of people can answer this riddle?" So, although @rand al'thor has responded to the longest word, the answer is Stack Exchange Puzzling users.

Comment: Upvoting this answer because it's getting closer to what I had in mind...

Comment: @hist How many were going to St. Ives...

Answer (score 7):

Prime letters:

> BCEGKMQSW

Since repetition is not specifically disallowed:

> `BESEEMS` (7)

If that's not "common" enough:

> `MESSES` and `EMCEES` (6)

Comment: "Emcees" is just "MC" or Master of Ceremonies, so I'm not sure that really counts.

Comment: As much as I agree, it's listed in the dictionary as both noun and verb. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emcee

Answer (score 5):

Here's a longer word considered valid by [Hasbro's Scrabble dictionary](http://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary):

> WEEWEES (7): TO URINATE. RELATED WORDS: WEEWEE/WEEWEED/WEEWEEING

<sub>I used [Litscape](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools_mammoth_uncensored/words_using_these_letters_only.php) which also suggested `beseekes` (8)  but I couldn't find any other source to validate it as a word.</sub>

Comment: It's an alternate spelling of beseeches. It appears from the etymology the ch once had the sound of k so the alternate spelling makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

The prime-numbered letters are:

> BCEGKMQSW

The longest words that can be made with these letters appears to be

> BECKS.

If you allow the letter A (even though 1 is usually taken to be neither prime nor composite), then the longest word made of only *those* letters would be

> WEBCAMS.

Answer (score 2):

> wee, week, meek, web geeks

Though that's more then one word, but a good string of bad adjectives may help.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> [meseems](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meseems)

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 18.</sup>